# How to select row from a table based on two values c#?

Tags: c#

I know how to select a row from a table base on one column value, like that:

```
var rowFeatureName = db.AfrRules.SingleOrDefault(r => r.FeatureName == FeatureName);
```

But how can I do the same thing based on two column?

Thanks

Comment: The [`&&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) still works in LINQ queries ya know...

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: No way for me to know if you are missing something because you never included what you tried in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do an AND operation

```
var rowFeatureName = db.AfrRules.Where(r => r.FeatureName == FeatureName && 
   r.FeatureName2 == FeatureName).FirstOrDefault();
```

or this for an OR operation

```
var rowFeatureName = db.AfrRules.Where(r => r.FeatureName == FeatureName || 
    r.FeatureName2 == FeatureName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Why the where clause? Just use the lambda expression inside the FirstOrDefault `db.AfrRules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.FeatureName == FeatureName && 
   r.FeatureName2 == FeatureName);`

Comment: Also, OP uses `SingleOrDefault()` you change to `FirstOrDefault()` without specifying why.  This would be good information for the OP to know